# C: 'the incompatible pointer types passing' warning is important?/Passing multi-dimentional array to function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I would like to write a function that takes a pointer to multidimensional array. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_matrix(int channel, int row, int column, int *matrix);

int main(void) {
    int test[4][5][6];
    int counter = 1;
    for (int channel = 0; channel < 4; channel++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 6; column++) {
                test[channel][row][column] = counter;
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    print_matrix(4, 5, 6, test);
}

void print_matrix(int channel, int row, int column, int *matrix) {
    for (int chn = 0; chn < channel; chn++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < column; c++) {
                printf("%d ", *(matrix + (chn * row * column + r * column + c)));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

But when I compile the code, the compiler gave following warning.

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [4][5][6]' to parameter of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Before I asked the question, I searched the warning and I found the different solution. like

```
void print_matrix(int channel, int row, int column, int matrix[channel][row][column]) ...
```

if I am not wrong, I know that C holds array as sequential. for example:

```
int holder[2][3][4]; // is equal to int holder[24] in ram
                     //holder[0][1][0] is equal to *(holder + 4)
```

My question is that the warning is important? and if I know what to do, can I ignore this warning?

Comment: You can use `print_matrix(4, 5, 6, &test[0][0][0]) ;`

Comment: Thanks. Would you like to tell me what is difference between test and &test[0][0][0]? Both of them indicate the same memory location but the compiler doesn't give any warning in &test[0][0][0] situation?

Comment: Every warning is important

Comment: The compiler is warning about a wrong type. Every variable has an address and a type. Type of `&test[0][0][0]` is simply `int*`. Type of `test` when passed as parameter decays to `int(*)[5][6]`

Comment: Imagine a red laser *pointer* that points to trains and point it to the train named `test`. The red laser spot will hit a seat, like a green laser pointer that points to seats (you can point to the first seat in the first carriage in the train named `test`). The two lasers hit the same spot, but they're very different ... and the generated machine code (but not the compiler) is color-blind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of warning is very important: in most cases, it indicates potential undefined behavior.

In your particular case, because you know the geometry of the object, and `test` decays to a pointer to its first element (a 2D matrix), which happens to have the same value as a pointer to the first matrix element, your code has the expected behavior.

Yet it would be better style to pass a pointer to the first matrix element explicitly:

```
int main(void) {
    int test[4][5][6];
    int counter = 1;
    for (int channel = 0; channel < 4; channel++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 6; column++) {
                test[channel][row][column] = counter;
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    print_matrix(4, 5, 6, &test[0][0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm little bit confused. What is difference between test and &test[0][0][0]? both of them indicate the same memory location.

Comment: yes, but there are not the same type. test is `int [4][5][6]` type, test[0] is `int [5][6]` type, test[0][0] is `int [6]` and test[0][0][0] is `int`. All of the previous variable indicate the same memory location (only because it's the actual array start), but the type aren't the same. And your function wait a `int *` type. Due to array decay, all of the previous expression is "converted" to `int *` which is what the function expect,, but the compiler throw a warning because your code should not have this kind of behavior (that the function wait a `int *` but you giving a `int [4][5][6]` )