# Passing a 2D array to a function and getting incompatible pointer type when compiling in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Hi so I have a super simple code below which creates a random 2D matrix based off a user input of the number of rows and columns. However whenever I compile the code, I get the error message:

```
test1.c:27:29: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘print_array’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   27 |     print_array(rows, cols, A);
      |                             ^
      |                             |
      |                             double (*)[(sizetype)(cols)]
test1.c:7:46: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[(sizetype)(cols)]’
    7 | void print_array(int rows, int cols, double *A);
```

with the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_VALS 2123

void print_array(int rows, int cols, double *A);

int main(){
    int cols, rows, n = 0;

    printf("Enter number of columns: \n");
    scanf("%d", &cols);

    printf("Enter number of rows: \n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    double A[rows][cols];

    for(int m=0;m<rows;m++){
        for(int n=0;n<cols;n++){
            A[m][n]=rand()%45+1;
            printf("A[%d,%d]=%f\n",m,n,A[m][n]);
        }
     }

     print_array(rows, cols, A);

     return 0;
}

void
print_array(int rows, int cols, double *A){
    printf("\n");
    int m,n;
    for (m=0;m<rows;m++){
        for (n=0;n<cols;n++){
            printf("A[%d,%d]=%f\n",m,n,A[m*cols+n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C: 'the incompatible pointer types passing' warning is important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68063801/c-the-incompatible-pointer-types-passing-warning-is-important)

Answer (score 0):

Call `print_array()` in this way:

```
print_array(rows, cols, A[0]);
```

or

```
print_array(rows, cols, (double *)A);
```